Umbraco Lucene Date Field Encoding convert to .net DateTime
I am trying to update an Umbraco site using Lucene for a site search function.
I am trying to display a list of search results and include the last time the search result was updated.
I found the field on the Examine.Lucene.Search.LuceneSearchResult called "updateDate".
When I check the field I get something like: 638502404046200000 for the value.
Does anyone know how to convert this field to a .net DateTime object?
Currently we used:
public static string LuceneDateTimeStamp(string adt)
{
   DateTime dt;
   adt = adt.Replace("-", "");
   if (adt.Length > 8) adt = adt.Substring(0, 8);

   DateTime.TryParseExact(adt, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
   return dt.ToString("D");
}

However this is not working and gives 1st January 0001. How do you convert the value into something meaningful to display on a search results page?

Seems to be a timestamp, did you try to read the value with DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(Int64.Parse(adt))

638502404046200000 is probably a DateTime.Ticks value:
public static DateTime ParseLuceneTimeStamp(string value)
{
    var ticks = long.Parse(value);
    return new DateTime(ticks);
}

